# Android Mount File System In Windows

Tags: android, windows, filesystems, root, mount

I want to edit some files on my phone but I can not access the root folder on my phone.
How can I mount the Android system file in Windows.

Comment: android.stackexchange.com

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111870/mount-android-phone-file-system-on-linux-manually